# Is it possible to use Jenkins Docker Agent with different AWS CLI credentials than host?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, terraform

I'm using a docker agent for terraform deployments on Jenkins. On my host I have AWS CLI configured to another AWS account, I don't want to use for this terraform deployments. Now I'm running the Jenkins deployment with a docker agent and on this agent, I want to change the account of that AWS CLI. For this I'm running the following commands:

```
                sh 'export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${ACCESS_KEY}"'
                sh 'export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${SECRET_KEY}"'
                sh 'export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="${SESSION_TOKEN}"'
```

The problem is, after I ran this commands the aws cli is still not using the new credentials, but the aws cli account configured on the host.
This is the docker command that jenkins uses to start the docker container:

```
docker run -t -d -u 1001:1001 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<name>/<pipeline_name> -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<name>/<pipeline_name>:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<name>/<pipeline_name>:rw,z -v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<name>/<pipeline_name>@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<name>/<pipeline_name>@tmp:rw,z -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** **** cat
```

This is the dockerfile in use as the agent:

```
FROM alpine:latest

MAINTAINER Leon

ARG GLIBC_VERSION=2.35-r0
ARG AWSCLI_VERSION=2.11.11

RUN apk --no-cache add \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && curl -sL https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub -o /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && curl -sLO https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && apk add --no-cache --force-overwrite \
        glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
        glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
        glibc-i18n-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk \
    && /usr/glibc-compat/bin/localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8 \
    && ln -sf /usr/glibc-compat/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 \
    && curl -sL https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-${AWSCLI_VERSION}.zip -o awscliv2.zip \
    && unzip awscliv2.zip \
    && aws/install \
    && rm -rf \
        awscliv2.zip \
        aws \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/aws_completer \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/data/ac.index \
        /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/examples \
        glibc-*.apk \
    && find /usr/local/aws-cli/v2/current/dist/awscli/botocore/data -name examples-1.json -delete \
    && apk --no-cache del \
        binutils \
        curl \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN apk add terraform --repository=https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
```

How can I tell the dockeragent, not to use the AWS credentials from the host? Or am I missing something?